# How to get database value to label filtered by combobox

Tags: c#, sql, forms, combobox, label

I have a combobox connected to a database which shows initials of employees. Now if I select an initial, I want a label to show the name of the employee that belongs to this initial.

What's wrong with my code?

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT Prename FROM Employee WHERE Initials=@Initials", conn);
        cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Initials", comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()));
        SqlDataReader PrenameReader;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            PrenameReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            while (PrenameReader.Read())
            {
                string sPrename = PrenameReader["Prename"].ToString(); 
                lblPrename.Text = sPrename;
            }

            conn.Close();
        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you getting any value in reader?

Comment: What is PreNameReader? why not use DataReader?

Comment: What is your query returns? Did you debug your code line by line? Are you sure you get the right value with `comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString`? Your query returns just one row or more than once? Because if it returns more than one rows, your `lblPrename.Text` assigned the last row value.

Comment: No I dont get any value.

Comment: @Dario If you don't get _any_ value, how do you expect to show them in a label(_or anywhere_)?

Comment: Every Inital only exists once so my query can only return one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your problem I think

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Initials", comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString()));
```

change it to

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Initials", comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()));
```

Or

```
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Initials", comboBox1.SelectedText);
```

whichever gives proper Initials.
Also I am not sure how many Values you will get from that query but if you want the first result either use `Top 1` in you select query or don't read all Data as it will only get the last record's value